# How to use a for loop to plot scatter plots

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a target variable y_data and predictor variables saved in X_data. Since I know all my X variables are numeric, I am trying to plot scatter plots of target variable against each X variable. My python codes are included here. However, my code will overlay all the scatter plots in 1 graph. How can I have them individually plotted and Xlabel individually added to each plot? Any help is appreciated!

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes()

for column in X_data:
    ax.plot(y_data, X_data[column],
   marker = 'o', ls='', ms = 3.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the creation of a figure inside the loop. Create a list of figures, then append to the list each individual figure:

```
figures = []

for column in X_data:
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    figures += [f]  # This appends a figure f to the list of figures
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.plot(y_data, X_data[column], marker = 'o', ls='', ms = 3.0)
```

This should do it, but I haven't tested the code.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to individually add xlabel to the figures?

Comment: Inside the loop:

   `ax.set_xlabel("Here is your label")`

or, maybe if you want to add a variable to the string

    `# Using the first element of the column as a label`
   `lbl_num = column[0]`
  `ax.set_xlabel(f"{lbl_num}")`